# Using sql in vba

Tags: sql, vba

I have tried to write a program to create queries in access using the sql as the following

```
For d = DateSerial(2011, 12, 4) To DateSerial(2011, 12, 10)

newSQL = " SELECT TAXIDATA.HkDt, TAXIDATA.DevID, TAXIDATA.HkTm, TAXIDATA.Lat, TAXIDATA.Lon, TAXIDATA.FlagDown" 'sql code
newSQL = newSQL & " FROM TAXIDATA"
newSQL = newSQL & " WHERE TAXIDATA.HkDt = #" & Format(d, "MM/dd/yyyy") & "# AND ((TAXIDATA.DevID)<"002000"))"
newSQL = newSQL & " ORDER BY TAXIDATA.HkDt, TAXIDATA.DevID, TAXIDATA.HkTm; "
```

However, there is a error when I run the 4th line. There is something wrong with ((TAXIDATA.DevID)<"002000"))" . TAXIDATA.DevID is a short text in the access. So I suppose "002000" will work just fine but it isn't.

Comment: You need to escape the "quote"

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape all double quote by using extra double quote.

```
newSQL = newSQL & " WHERE TAXIDATA.HkDt = #" & Format(d, ""MM/dd/yyyy"") & "# AND ((TAXIDATA.DevID)<""002000""))"
```